# ¿Cúal es la mejor forma de guardar una imagen en la base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo una duda de como guardar una imagen en la base de datos, se que hay dos formas, una guardar la ruta de la imagen y la otra guardar la imagen en binario.
pero no se cuál de las dos formas es mejor. 
Gracias.

Comment: solo el nombre de la imagen....

Comment: guarda el nombre de la imagen, como mucho la ruta, evita guardar datos que se repitan y evita guardar datos binarios.

Answer (score -1):

Es mejor la ruta de esta, ya que se carga menos la BD, además, es menos complicado, menos complicado y más eficiente, creo que ahí está la respuesta, buen día

Comment: ¿Mejor para quíén?

Comment: Mejor para el desarrollador...